# Firebase get timestamp ? Android Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Cloud firestore , how i can get the local time in document snapshots ? im always getting an error , i need a local time.

```
CollectionReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("chats").document(id).collection("messages");
docRef.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                System.err.println("Listen failed: " + e);
                return;
            }
            if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {

                for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {

                    Timestamp time = (Timestamp) data.get("time"); // sometimes has been crash
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: As mentioned before, if possible, please update your question with the error message and stacktrace of the error you are getting.